# How to Have Multi Images on One Item of Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please let me know how I can load several images on one `.item` of Bootstrap carousel?

As you can see from [This Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/er7qf907/) I am trying an output like this

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

but the images are presenting under each other.

Here is the code I have

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://www.neverendingtech.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/businessman.png" alt="">
      <img src="http://www.wallscapeinc.com/images/businessman1.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And exactly for your example:

```css
/* All images, but not the first */
.carousel-inner > .item img + img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://www.neverendingtech.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/businessman.png" alt="">
      <img src="http://www.wallscapeinc.com/images/businessman1.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://www.wallscapeinc.com/images/businessman1.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below link to display multi image carousel 1 item per time using bootstrap carousel.

http://www.bootply.com/tagged/carousel

http://www.bootply.com/JAHTzGyft6